# Quadratic residue problem involving prime divisors of a polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, quadratic-residues

Let $n$ be a square-free  natural number, and let $f\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be monic and irreducible of degree $\geq2$. I am trying to determine whether there always exists a prime $p$, $p\nmid n$, satisfying both of the following conditions:

1. $\left(\frac{-n}{p}\right)=1$;
2. $f(x)=0$ is solvable modulo $p$.

I know that the Chebotarev Density Theorem implies that primes satisfying 1. have density 1/2, and I also know that there are infinitely primes satisfying 2. I'm not sure if this is known, or how hard this problem is, but any references would be very welcome.

Comment: With 2 you mean that there is a root of $f$ modulo $p$? You get a positive answer by applying Chebotarev to the compositum of the splitting field of $f$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-n})$.

Comment: @Wojowu yes, that's what I mean for 2. I edited the question, thanks.
Would you mind expanding a bit on your answer? If $K$ is the composite field, then what would the conjugation invariant subset $X$ of $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ that I apply Chebotarev to be?

Comment: Just the identity. A prime with trivial Frobenius in that compositum will have trivial Frobenius in both subfields, which implies the respective conditions.

Comment: I should add that for the correct (positive) logarithmic density of splitting primes one does not need Chebotarev. One simply needs that the Dedekind zeta function has a simple pole at $s=1$, then take the logarithmic derivative, and observe that non-splitting primes only contribute $O(1)$ around $s=1$.

Comment: @Wojowu thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: @GHfromMO that is so much simpler, thank you!

Comment: I'd appreciate it if someone would post an answer (based on the comments).